# Mobile Internet Carriers in Eastern Europe

Tags: cellphones, internet

So, I will travel to a bunch of countries in Eastern Europe soon and I would like to have internet access in my cellphone. I've already bought in other trips pre-paid SIMs, but as far as I'm concerned as soon as you leave the country you bought it in, it stops working. Are there any carriers that provide international internet access for these countries? Poland, Czech Republic, Slovakia and Austria

Comment: Every EU sim card works in every other EU country. Can you be more specific? Otherwise the answer is "every single carrier".

Comment: I mean without paying for roaming, like a ""international"" SIM

Comment: No "international" sims will be cheaper than getting a prepaid card for every country.